# How to configure Dell g3 3579 fingerprint in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: drivers, usb, dell, fingerprint-reader

I referred the article/question on Ask Ubuntu / Stackoverflow but I didn't find the answer to configure the fingerprint.

> Commands that I use

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 27c6:5301 Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. Fingerprint Reader
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:6a06 Microdia Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 2717:ff88 Xiaomi Inc. Mi/Redmi series (RNDIS + ADB)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188EUS 802.11n Wireless Network Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Reference https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/sp3iky/how_to_enable_fingerprint_login_in_ubuntu_on_dell/?rdt=46709